# Tsung how to get the controller id

Tags: tsung

I know that it is possible to set a id to the controller in tsung using the flag -i, i.e, tsung start -i ID. My question is It is possible retrieve that id in the tsung.xml?

Answer (score 0):

e.g.

```
<setdynvars sourcetype="eval"
code='fun({Pid,DynVars})->
    case string:tokens(atom_to_list(node()),"@") of
       ["tsung_controller_"++ID,_] -> list_to_integer(ID);
       _ -> 0 end end.'>
<var name="controller_id" />
</setdynvars>
```